# Import exisiting Spring Context into Grails 3.0.1 app

Tags: spring, grails

I have an exisiting Spring application in Java and I want to add a Grails web app to it and reuse the domain model and my beans from the Spring context. I already created a `hibernate.cfg.xml` which from what I have read should integrate the domain model. But when trying to integrate the Spring ApplicationContext, I run into the following Problem/Exception:

`Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: A circular @Import has been detected: Illegal attempt by @Configuration class 'AppContext' to import class 'AppContext' as 'AppContext' is already present in the current import stack [ImportStack: [AppContext]]`

My `resources.groovy` file looks like this:

`beans = {
    importBeans('file:grails-app/conf/spring/applicationContext-spring.xml')
}`

In this xml-file, I just import my Java-config class for my Spring Java application.

I also get this circular import error when trying to define my `AppContext` class directly in the `resources.groovy`. (I assume because the code then does exactly the same.)

The error looks to me as if my `AppContext` is already imported by the Grais context, but when trying to use it, the beans are not present and I get the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` when trying to access them.

My question now: Does anyone know how to properly integrate my Spring context into a new Grails app?

Program version:

- Java 8
- Spring 4.1.0
- Groovy 2.4.3
- Grails 3.0.1
- Gradle 2.4